# How to create index for conditional selected sort fields query in Firebase?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

For example, in Firestore I have JSON like this

```
// Document 1
{
  "type":"Child",
  "createdDate":"01/01/2020",
  "birthDate":"08/01/2002",
}

// Document 2
{
  "type":"Adult",
  "createdDate":"05/01/2020",
  "birthDate":"08/01/1990",
}
```

I want to turn this function in to firebase query

```
(a, b) {
  DateTime da = a["type"] == "Child" ? a["createdDate"]: a["birthDate"];
  DateTime db = a["type"] == "Child" ? a["createdDate"]: a["birthDate"];
  return da.compareTo(db);
}
// In short if it a Child, select `createdDate` to compare, else select `birthDate` to compare.
```

Can I do this in firebase?

I can't query all data then sort in frontend because I want to use [FirestoreListView](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutterfire_ui/latest/firestore/FirestoreListView-class.html)

Comment: you mean you have two different list? or all the `Adult` and `Child` are in the same list?

Comment: @eamirho3ein
Both documents are in the same collection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I see, is to create a helper field in the DB which shows the createdDate for children and the birthDate for adults. Then you can sort for this field

Comment: If I already have data (like thousands document), does firebase has a tool to do this, or I have to write a console command?

Answer (score 2):

I have not your Class model so I run the logic on the list but you can do this on model too.

First you can't sort a list with two different sort, I recommend first split those into two group as `child` and `adult`, then sort theme then merge them together, for grouping I used [collection](https://pub.dev/packages/collection) package, let say this is your list:

```
List<Map<String, String>> dataList = [
    {
      "type": "Child",
      "createdDate": "08/01/2020",
      "birthDate": "09/01/2002",
    },
    {
      "type": "Child",
      "createdDate": "01/01/2020",
      "birthDate": "08/01/2002",
    },
    {
      "type": "Adult",
      "createdDate": "05/01/2020",
      "birthDate": "10/01/1990",
    },
    {
      "type": "Adult",
      "createdDate": "05/01/2020",
      "birthDate": "08/01/1990",
    },
  ];
```

you can sort them like this:

```
var grouped = groupBy(dataList, (Map value) => value['type']);

var result = grouped.entries
    .map((e) {
      e.value.sort(
        (a, b) => e.key == "Child"
            ? a["createdDate"]
                .toString()
                .compareTo(b["createdDate"].toString())
            : a["birthDate"]
                .toString()
                .compareTo(b["birthDate"].toString()),
      );
      return e.value;
    })
    .toList()
    .expand((element) => element)
    .toList();
```

**result:**

```
[
   {type: Child, createdDate: 01/01/2020, birthDate: 08/01/2002},
   {type: Child, createdDate: 08/01/2020, birthDate: 09/01/2002},
   {type: Adult, createdDate: 05/01/2020, birthDate: 08/01/1990},
   {type: Adult, createdDate: 05/01/2020, birthDate: 10/01/1990}
]
```

Comment: I think you don't understand me. I just edit my post to be more clearly. Sorry for bad English

Comment: sorry I did't understand your issue, can you explain more?

Comment: I want to query using firebase firestore, not flutter sort